# Spring @ComponentScan not detecting REST controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

After searching various similar question on StackOverflow, I have determined that most people suffering from this issue are not properly scanning the module where their controller lives.  Some solutions call for combining the files that are to be scanned into the same module as the Application (which works), but I do not want to move any of my .java files.  Instead, I'd like to make `@ComponentScan` work.

I have the following project structure

```
Project
      |
      settings.gradle
      build.gradle
      module1
            |
            src/main/java/com.test.application
            |                                |
            |                                Application.java
            |                                SwaggerConfig.java
            build.gradle
      module2
            |
            src/main/java/com.test.service
            |                            |
            |                            Service.java
            |                            Controller.java
            build.gradle
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Note here that I am scanning `com.test` in my component scan.  I can't find anything in the [@ComponentScan documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) (or on StackOverflow) that would suggest I am using `@ComponentScan` incorrectly.

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class GearParsingController {
  private SomeService someService;

  @Autowired
  public SomeController(SomeService someService) {
    this.someService = someService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/path")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getSomeService() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Default message", HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}
```

**module1 build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':module2')

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
}
```

**module2 build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'

    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.5.0-RC2'
}
```

When I try to access my endpoints at `localhost:8080/test/path` I am met with:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-29T19:19:52.275+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/test/path"
}
```

When launching the program in debug mode, I am given the following output:

```
2019-06-29 13:58:58.345  INFO 8272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-06-29 13:58:58.387  INFO 8272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-29 13:58:58.387  INFO 8272 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-06-29 13:58:58.522  INFO 8272 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-29 13:58:58.522 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2019-06-29 13:58:58.522  INFO 8272 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1786 ms
2019-06-29 13:58:58.544 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*], hiddenHttpMethodFilter urls=[/*], formContentFilter urls=[/*], requestContextFilter urls=[/*]
2019-06-29 13:58:58.545 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]
2019-06-29 13:58:58.583 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use
2019-06-29 13:58:58.583 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] .s.b.w.s.f.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter : Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured for use
2019-06-29 13:58:58.583 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2019-06-29 13:58:58.584 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedFormContentFilter     : Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use
2019-06-29 13:58:58.896 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 5 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2019-06-29 13:58:58.990  INFO 8272 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2019-06-29 13:58:59.045 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/**/favicon.ico] in 'faviconHandlerMapping'
2019-06-29 13:58:59.128  INFO 8272 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-29 13:58:59.146 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2019-06-29 13:58:59.257 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2019-06-29 13:58:59.263 DEBUG 8272 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2019-06-29 13:58:59.442  INFO 8272 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2019-06-29 13:58:59.481  INFO 8272 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2019-06-29 13:58:59.519  INFO 8272 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
```

So, my question is: **Why isn't ComponentScan detecting my REST controller?**

Comment: These separate "folders" look like separate modules/jars, and you don't show a dependency from the launcher to the implementation. (As a note, set logging on `org.springframework.web` to DEBUG and you'll get a listing of every Web mapping at startup.)

Comment: @chrylis folder1's build.gradle has a dependency on the folder2 module.  I have updated my question to make this more clear.  If this is not what you meant, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Turn up your debug logs (you might get by launching the application in debug mode, as with `--debug` or your IDE's settings) to see about MVC registration.

Comment: @buratino Just to be sure check com/test/application are declared as packages not as single package with name "com.test.application"

Comment: @chrylis I have added the output to my post.

Comment: @AnuragSharma I have confirmed through intelliJ project structure that they are indeed separate packages.

Comment: your first module, needs to have a dependency on module number two

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I have updated the post to be more explicit about this.  I believe I am correctly importing a dependency of `module2` in `module1`

Comment: have you even tried scanning `com.test.service`?

Comment: post the second module build script. you "belive" that you are importing it correct. Can you verify it? look in the jar? try using a class from module2 in module1.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I have correctly set module2 as a dependency in module1 via gradle.  I have updated my post to show the current gradle structure for the top-level build.gradle and the two module build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your files this way:

**Project build.gradle** (removed spring plugin application to all module projects)

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

**module1 build.gradle** (apply spring plugins and bootJar goal)

```html
dependencies {
    implementation project(':module2')

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'module1'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

**module2 build.gradle** (added jar goal)

```html
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'module2'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```html
include 'module1'
include 'module2'
```

Point is that we want second module built as normal jar and the main module as spring boot runnable. With that setup just `gradle build` and then `gradle bootRun` from main project folder.

Comment: How can this solution be extended out when other modules with different controllers are added to the project?

Comment: Just add them the same way as `module2`, is there any problem with doing it?

Comment: Similar issue but using maven, no gradle. Are you saying we cannot use springboot as a dependency for non-application modules? Need underlying spring-web/data/core dependencies instead? Is there no annotation to tell spring which packages to check for RestControllers?

Comment: No, there should be no problem using those dependencies in other modules, i do that everywhere. You can then use ComponentScan, Import or other possible options - good article about it -> https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-modules/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to pick up your controller from the "com.test" package use the basePackages option of the @ComponentScan:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
```

Comment: That is equivalent to the syntax I've used, as per ComponentScan's [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#value--): *Allows for more concise annotation declarations if no other attributes are needed — for example, @ComponentScan("org.my.pkg") instead of @ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.my.pkg").*

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you have your main Application.java class on a similar package hierarchy as all the other components - src/main/java/com.test.application & src/main/java/com.test.service.  If you move your Application.java one package above, it's more likely to scan properly: e.g Put your Application.java in the package: src/main/java/com/test

Comment: I would like the keep the package hierarchy as is.  I'll update that into my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your main application `Application.java` is under the directory `com.test.application` , which means that when the springboot application starts up by default the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation will look for beans and configurations under the packgae `com.test.application` . In the springboot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html) it is specified that we should place the Main application under the root package so that spring scans everything under it.

> @SpringBootApplication is a convenience annotation that adds all of
>   the following:
>
> - @Configuration tags the class as a source of bean definitions for the    application context.
> - @EnableAutoConfiguration tells Spring Boot to start adding beans    based on classpath settings, other beans, and various property
>     settings.
> - Normally you would add @EnableWebMvc for a Spring MVC app, but Spring    Boot adds it automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the
>     classpath. This flags the application as a web application and
>     activates key behaviors such as setting up a DispatcherServlet.
> - @ComponentScan tells Spring to look for other components,    configurations, and services in the hello package, allowing it to
>     find the controllers.

So, to fix your issue try moving your main application to the root of your package 
`com.test` or you could use the annotation `@ComponentScan` to specify which all packages are needed to be scanned like :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
```

Comment: @buratino Can you try moving your main application to the root of your packgae ? Also verify that your build.gradle is configured correctly so that the module 2 is also compiled.

Comment: Moving the main application into module2 worked just fine.  However, I would like to keep the main application in module1 and use component scan instead.

Comment: Try to replace SpringBootApplication annotation with EnableAutoConfiguration and Configuration. Maybe ComponentScan from SpringBootApplication is overriding ComponentScan that you wrote.

Comment: @buratino Intead of moving main application to com.test in module 2 try moving it to com.test in module 1 itself that should work and it would not mean a huge change in structure of your application right.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Boot convention, controllers have to be in the `com.test.controller` package.

Comment: Could you provide your source?

Comment: do you mean an example or a source of the fact I said? If the second one it’s just my experience. I also had the same problem a couple of times.